# Como fazer comparacoes(e alteracoes) entre tipos float e string com .loc

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Estou tentando reduzir a variabilidade de uma var. float para uma categórica:

```
df['DDD'] = df['DDD'].astype(float)
df.loc[df['DDD']> '90.0', 'DDD']= 'Norte'
df.loc[df['DDD']> '80.0', 'DDD']= 'Nordeste'
df.loc[df['DDD']> '70.0', 'DDD']= 'Bahia'
df.loc[df['DDD']> '60.0', 'DDD']= 'Centro_Oeste'
df.loc[df['DDD']> '50.0', 'DDD']= 'RS'
df.loc[df['DDD']> '40.0', 'DDD']= 'SC_PR'
df.loc[df['DDD']> '30.0', 'DDD']= 'MG'
df.loc[df['DDD']> '20.0', 'DDD']= 'RJ_ES'
```

Porem recebo o seguinte erro:

TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=float64 and str

Tentei o caminho inverso declarando DDD como string de início. Ele roda, porém acumula todos os valores no último teste lógico 'RJ_ES'

Qual a melhor forma de tratar essa coluna com o teste logico passado?

Comment: O certo seria `df.loc[df['DDD']> 90, 'DDD']= 'Norte'`. Ou seja, uma vez que você transformou em `float`, compare com número (ex: `90`) e não com string (ex: `'90.0'`)

Comment: @PauloMarques obrigado pelo apoio! Eu tentei isso tambem. Era o mais intuitivo digo, porem ele também exibe a msg  que nao se pode comparar floats e strings

Answer (score -2):

Nao entendi se "feri" alguma regra da comunidade, mas depois de tentar de tudo consegui uma solucao alternativa pro problema acima usando **isin**. Fica o aprendizado

```
mask_norte = df.DDD.isin(list(range(90,100)))
df.loc[mask_norte, 'DDD']= 'Norte'

mask_nordeste = df.DDD.isin(list(range(80,90)))
df.loc[mask_nordeste, 'DDD']= 'Nordeste'

mask_bahia = df.DDD.isin(list(range(70,80)))
df.loc[mask_bahia, 'DDD']= 'Bahia'

mask_centroO = df.DDD.isin(list(range(60,70)))
df.loc[mask_centroO, 'DDD']= 'Centro_Oeste'

mask_RS = df.DDD.isin(list(range(50,60)))
df.loc[mask_RS, 'DDD']= 'RS'

mask_SC_PR = df.DDD.isin(list(range(40,50)))
df.loc[mask_SC_PR, 'DDD']= 'SC_PR'

mask_MG = df.DDD.isin(list(range(30,40)))
df.loc[mask_MG, 'DDD']= 'MG'

mask_RJ_ES = df.DDD.isin(list(range(20,30)))
df.loc[mask_RJ_ES, 'DDD']= 'RJ_ES'
```